# React native conditionally showing alert Native Base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

i have this alert component that returns a Native Base alert component

```
function CustomAlert() {
  const { alert, setAlert } = useAuthContext();
  const clearAlert = () => setAlert({ status: "", message: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (alert.message) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearAlert();
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [alert]);

  if (!alert.message) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <Alert w="90%" status="error" variant="solid" mx="auto" mt={10}>
      <VStack space={2} flexShrink={1} w="100%">
        <HStack
          flexShrink={1}
          space={2}
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <HStack space={2} flexShrink={1} alignItems="center">
            <AntDesign name="warning" size={14} color="#DEDEDE" />
            <Text fontSize="sm" color="coolGray.200">
              Qualquer mensagem
            </Text>
          </HStack>
          <AntDesign
            name="close"
            size={12}
            color="#DEDEDE"
            onPress={clearAlert}
          />
        </HStack>
      </VStack>
    </Alert>
  );
}

export default CustomAlert;
```

After the `alert` is fired i want it to vanish in 5 seconds, hence the `useEffect`. If there's no message i return nothing. But for some reason it's not working. The `alert` changes but it's not showing anything on screen.

Comment: This could be the issue of using setTimeout in useEffect. You need to make it's only load once and clear it when component destory. Read this https://felixgerschau.com/react-hooks-settimeout/

Answer (score 0):

Try to observe `alert.message` too because you can return the same object from `useAuthContext`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (alert.message) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearAlert();
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [alert, alert?.message]);
```